# Layout control for elements with a distributed width

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, layout

I'm not exactly sure how to phrase this question, so I'll just explain what I'm trying to do. I have a Model/ViewModel that essentially contains a list of elements. Some elements on the list should be represented with a static-width shape (such as a 10x10 pixel rectangle) whereas others should stretch to equally distribute the remaining width between all elements.

For example, let's assume the list contains the following:

(static static dynamic dynamic dynamic static dynamic dynamic)

The static elements have a width of 10px. I want each of the dynamic elements to equally take up the remaining room in the container. For example, if my container has 100 pixels, since I have 3 static elements, I want the rest of the 70 pixels to be distributed across the 5 dynamic elements (14 pixels each).

Is there a WPF control that does this or will I need to dynamically re-size and add the controls on window resize?

Comment: could you create like a enum or a static array depicting the size and widths..?

Comment: @DJKRAZE I suppose that is workable. I guess I could calculate the width and put it in the ViewModel as a DependencyProperty and the elements could bind to that. The ViewModel would then have to listen for Window changed events and update the width appropriately.

Comment: IMO a ViewModel isn't the best place for this. This is strictly view-related. Binding the window width to the ViewModel would be a step too far for me.

Answer (score 2):

In a [`Grid`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.grid.aspx) (- read this -) you can have rows and columns do that, change the [`RowDefiniton.Height`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.rowdefinition.height.aspx)/[`ColumnDefiniton.Width`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.columndefinition.width.aspx) to `Auto` to size to content and to `*` to distribute remainding space.

Comment: Don't the ColumnDefinitions have to be made in advance? Is it possible to do this purely in XAML?

Comment: @sohum: Yes they do. You could implement a control which manages the definitions based on the items added though.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you could use a standard Grid control. Add a column for each element, and set the column width to a specific size for those elements that require it, and use * for the remaining elements.

Comment: Again, see answer above. When you say "add a column for each element" it appears like I would need to either know the number of elements in advance or use the code-behind to populate the grid. I want to be able to do this in pure XAML, if possible.

Comment: @sohum: Yes, you'd have to do this in code-behind. But I don't see the problem people have with code-behind in WPF. If the framework doesn't solve your problem and it's view-related code then the code needs to go somewhere! Alternatively, if you need to be able to reuse the layout, your best best is creating a new Panel class.

Comment: I agree, there's no Panel which will do what you need through binding.  The closest is Grid, but Row/ColumnDefinitions are not dependency properties so you can't do it.  You need to do a bit of code behind (horrible I know).